# Campaign or countryside: Which one I've to use?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm translating a Italian review in English and I've a doubt.

Are there any difference between "campaign" and "countryside"? Which one I've to use and when?

Comment: I'm more curious to know how these two words are even remotely related in any language.

Comment: @JoeDark Italian for countryside is _campagna_. Italian for campaign is _campagna_. :) See my answer for the Latin origin.

Comment: In English, we say *I have a question*, not *I have a doubt*.

Answer (score 2):

In English countryside means "a rural area".

In English campaign means "actions taken to achieve a goal" as in *a military campaign, an election campaign* or *to take part in a campaign*.

Despite the Latin root of campaign (from Latin *campus*, field) and the  countryside being full of fields, countryside and campaign have no relationship in English. Use countryside when you mean physical area of a country, use campaign when you mean actions taken.